# React Native StatusBar: dark-content not working on android

Tags: react-native, statusbar

I'm trying to change the color of the title and the icons of the status-bar to be black.
so, according to the react-native status-bar documentation, I set the `barStyle` to `dark-content` but nothing change.

`<StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" backgroundColor={'white'} />`

Comment: Hi..were you able to fix it, please?

Comment: same issue, 'dark-content' not working on android. it's default props ('light-content") will displayed.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using **Expo** you should work with their own **Statusbar**.
You can install it by running:

```
expo install expo-status-bar
```

and modify it like this:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
...
   <StatusBar style="dark" />
...
```

Otherwise you may want to try upgrading Your version of react native by running:

```
npx react-native upgrade
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try to do the following:

```
import {StatusBar} from "react-native"

...

StatusBar.setBackgroundColor('white');
StatusBar.setBarStyle('dark-content');
```

with *useEffect* or *componentDidMount* methods.

Answer (score 3):

I was tearing my hair out until I just ran `npm run android` to rebuild and it just magically started working. So tip, if you do any StatusBar sourcery, rebuild fresh on Android.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. Make sure your 'StatusBar' component is being imported from 'react-native' and not from 'expo-status-bar'. It works for me now that I'm using the 'StatusBar' component from 'react-native'

Answer (score -1):

As said on [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26369), you can try upgrade to a newer version of react-native (If yours isn't the newest) and see if it works.

Comment: that issue was for iOs, but here the problem is for android.