# StatusBar React Native style following from screen to screen Android

Tags: android, css, react-native, statusbar

I'm having a StatusBar issue. On the home screen of my app I've set the StatusBar styles to how I want them for the sign-up/login flow.

```
      {Platform.OS === 'android' && 
        <StatusBar
          translucent
          backgroundColor={'transparent'}
          animated={false}
        />
      }
```

At a certain screen I want to update the `barstyle={dark-content')` but it is not updating on that screen or subsequent screens.

I have tried to set it in a `useEffect` hook so when the page renders it is set and have also tried to set it within the render.

This is specifically for Android that this is happening, iOS seems to work as expected. I appreciate y'all. If I can provide further context please let me know.

Comment: are you using react-navigation by any chance? Also, the (docs)[https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar#barstyle] mention that the `barstyle` prop only has effect on android devices running API 23+

Comment: hi @Moistbobo thanks for your response. I am using react-navigation in the app. The device I am testing on is API 30 thats why I'm surprised it isn't updating.

Comment: could it be a typo? `barStyle` instead of `barstyle`

Comment: reading through these [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/status-bar/) I am doing the same thing. When landing on a screen if I need to update the look of the status bar I set in in the render. Definitely not a typo unfortunately.

Comment: is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59805614/react-native-statusbar-dark-content-not-working-on-android) relevant?

Comment: I read through that thread and unfortunately no it doesn't apply. I took the statusbar out of the app,js file so each screen can determine its own settings and still nada on the android. I have a feeling its because the `translucent` property but can't find anythink to back that up haha.